# git recognizes directory as file

Tags: git, ubuntu

A recent issue has arised.

I have my local copy of code at `~/code/` directory where I made a `git init`. Whenever I copied a folder with files within it, git recognized folders and files normally.

This is the output of ls -l of ~/code/:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 david david 4096 oct 30 15:20 hw0
drwxrwxr-x 4 david david 4096 oct 30 15:20 hw1
drwxrwxr-x 4 david david 4096 oct 30 15:20 hw1.5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david   82 oct 30 15:20 README.md
```

But today I copied a folder and when I did a `git status`, git recognized `hw2/` folder as a file. Additionally, I removed `.git` folder and reinitialized git and now every folder is recognized as file.

Now the output is this for git status:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       README.md
#       hw0/
#       hw1.5/
#       hw1/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

All of those four items in color red. hw2/ is not in the list because I moved it to another directory because the code in it I fear it to be lost.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -la` within your `~/code` directory here?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "git recognized `hw2/` folder as a file"? What was the output of `git status` that led you to conclude this? How was this different from what you expected?

Comment: ls -l and output of git status added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described seems perfectly normal. Yes, Git lists your directories in the "Untracked files" section, but it indicates directories with a trailing `/`. What that means is Git is not tracking any of the files *within* that directory.

To remove directories such as `hw0/` from your list of untracked files, add one or more files within that directory to Git using `git add`.

Comment: except for the fact that I do have files within those folders. When I added the hw2 folder to my repo, github recognized it as a subproject. you can see the history here: https://github.com/dbarrerap/SaaS-CS169.1x/commits/master

Comment: did I mention the folders in the untracked files are color red?

Comment: I believe SO mininterpreted your answer, and so did I. That last dot should be part of the statement. `git add .` does the trick... although github still recognizes it as a separate project... =(